# how to use square sprite asset in isometric tilemap?

Tags: unity, 2d, isometric

I recently need to build a isometric game world in **Unity**. I have 4 types of terrain.Both are 32x32 square sprite.(represent 1x1 area) Besides, i have a table sprite asset which is already isometric.
[image]
how to make this two look perfect like this pic:
[image]

By using one tilemap:Is there anyway to make square to be diamond in Isometric tilemap?
Or I need to use two tilemap for each part?

I try to make square sprites on floor. And the Camera rotate (30,45,0)  table rotates too, but look weird.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to rotate and scale the square tiles in a graphic editor to turn them into rhombuses?

Comment: Alternatively, I described an approach to draw an isometric floor with square tiles [in the answer to this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47388/best-technique-for-drawing-isometric-tiles/47401#47401). You didn't say what technology you are using, so I don't know if it is feasible, because it requires that you can set a transformation matrix before drawing tiles.

Comment: Thx bro. I use unity, but your answer give me some inspiration.I am grateful for your support.

Comment: That you are using Unity is a very important piece of information. I added the Unity tag to your question. When you post any more question in the future, please always include the relevant tag for the game engine, framework or programming language you are using. This usually gets you more answers from more knowledgeable users, because people who consider themselves experts in a technology usually set those tags on "watched", which means that any questions about them get highlighted for them.

Comment: I am new here, some places are not doing well enough. I understand the information you mentioned and it is very helpful to me.Thanks a lot！

Comment: You may be interested in the [technique I show in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/206850/39518), where you can put your square floor tiles flat on the XZ plane and your isometric sprites standing upright, then use the camera projection to apply the isometric angle and correct for foreshortening.